# what is the difference between super(type, obj) and super(type, type)

Tags: python, super

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    # Getter function
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    # Setter function
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):       
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError('Expected a string')
        print(self)
        self._name = value
    # Deleter function
    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete attribute")

class SubPerson(Person):
    @property
    def name(self):
        print('Getting name')
        return super().name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        print('Setting name to', value)
        super(SubPerson, SubPerson).name.__set__(self, value)
    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        print('Deleting name')
        super(SubPerson, SubPerson).name.__delete__(self)

s = SubPerson('Guido')
print(s.name)
```

when i make the `super(SubPerson, SubPerson).name.__set__(self, value)` to
`super(SubPerson, self).name.__set__(self, value)`, i get this issue

```
AttributeError: 'SubPerson' object has no attribute '_name'
```

Why?

Comment: did you mean `self._name = name` in `Person.__init__`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I think you didn't understand this code, please run it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super(SubPerson, SubPerson)` is a proxy to access overridden attributes of `SubPerson`, but `super(SubPerson, self)` is a proxy to access overridden attributes of *`self`*. By this, I mean that while it searches through class dicts for attribute lookup, it performs descriptor handling for instance attributes rather than class attributes.

`super(SubPerson, self).name` finds the `name` property in `Person.__dict__`. It then *calls `__get__`* automatically. The getter tries to read `self._name`, which doesn't exist, hence your error.

Comment: But `s = SubPerson('Guido')` will run `super(SubPerson, self).name.__set__(self, value)` and next `super(Person, self).name.__set__(self, value)` and then  `self._name = value`

Comment: @coordinate: The `super(SubPerson, self).name` in `super(SubPerson, self).name.__set__(self, value)` calls `__get__`. It won't give you the property object to call `__set__` with.